# Read a file line by line with specific data C++

Tags: c++, file, stream

I have a file with this format:

```
11
1 0
2 8 0
3 8 0
4 5 10 0
5 8 0
6 1 3 0
7 5 0
8 11 0
9 6 0
10 5 7 0
11 0
```

The first line is the number of lines, so I can make a loop to read the file with the number of lines.
For the other lines, I would like to read the file line by line and store the data until I get a "0" on the line that's why there is a 0 at the end of each line.
The first column is the task name.
The others columns are the constraints name.

I tried to code something but It doesn't seem to work

```
printf("Constraints :\n");
for (int t = 1; t <= numberofTasks; t++) 
{
    F >> currentTask;
    printf("%c\t", currentTask);
    F >> currentConstraint;
    while (currentConstraint != '0') 
    {
        printf("%c", currentConstraint);
        F >> currentConstraint;
    };
    printf("\n");
};
```

The "0" represents the end of the constraints for a task.

I think my code doesn't work properly because the constraint 10 for the task 4 contains a "0" too.

Thanks in advance for your help

Regards

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: what do you mean by "edit your question to contain" ?

Comment: Which word you do not understand in particular?

Comment: Why are you mixing the streams?  Either stick with C++ I/O (`operator>>`) or use C I/O streams (`printf`).

Comment: What type `currentConstraint` is? Without complete code it is everyone's guess but yours. This is what Slava was trying to tell you, post Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example

Comment: I recommend using `std::getline` and `std::string` to read in a line of text.  You can use `std::istringstream` to read in the numbers from the string.

Comment: You may find Option 2 of the first answer to [Read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line) to be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are reading individual characters from the file, not reading whole integers, or even line-by-line.  Change your `currentTask` and `currentConstraint` variables to `int` instead of `char`, and use `std::getline()` to read lines that you then read integers from.

Try this:

```
F >> numberofTasks;
F.ignore();

std::cout << "Constraints :" << std::endl;
for (int t = 1; t <= numberofTasks; ++t) 
{
    std::string line;
    if (!std::getline(F, line)) break;

    std::istringstream iss(line);

    iss >> currentTask;
    std::cout << currentTask << "\t";

    while ((iss >> currentConstraint) && (currentConstraint != 0))
    {
        std::cout << currentConstraint << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/s4k8M1)

That being said, the terminating `0` on each line is unnecessary.  `std::getline()` will stop reading when it reaches the end of a line, and `operator>>` will stop reading when it reaches the end of the stream.

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/tPTO63)

Comment: I see what you did, you just read until the end of the line, instead of reading until a 0. And we only take constraints different from 0. Thanks for your help